# having multiple keys in one key of an array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, key

I want to have multiple keys in one key of an array. I tried the following syntax:

```
<?php
for($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++){
    $str = 'name'.$i;
    if ($i == 0){
        $date = 'today';
    }
    elseif ($i == 1){
        $date = 'yesterday';
    }
    else{
        $date = 'tomorrow';
    }
    if ($date == "yesterday"){
        $arr[] = ["user" => $str, "time" => '2020-10-2'];
    }
    elseif ($date == "today"){
        $arr[] = ["user" => $str, "time" => '2020-10-3'];
    }
    elseif ($date == "tomorrow"){
        $arr[] = ["user" => $str, "time" => '2020-10-4'];
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

but the result array seems to only have one element.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => name1
            [time] => 2020-10-2
        )

)
```

I don't know what's happening. help is appreciated.

**Update:**
I'm sharing this 'cause apparantly the above code doesn't show the problem I have. This is the actual code:

```
<?php
$txt_file = fopen('path.txt', 'r');
$date = strtotime(fgets($txt_file));
$arr = [];
for($i = 0 ; !feof($txt_file) ; $i++){
    $str = explode(':', fgets($txt_file));
    if (count($str) != 2){
        continue;
    }
    if ($str[1] == "yesterday"){
        $arr[] = ["user" => $str[0], "time" => date("Y-m-d", $date-3600*24)];
    }
    elseif ($str[1] == "today"){
        $arr[] = ["user" => $str[0], "time" => date("Y-m-d", $date)];
    }
    elseif ($str[1] == "tomorrow"){
        $arr[] = ["user" => $str[0], "time" => date("Y-m-d", $date+3600*24)];
    }
}
file_put_contents("INFO.json", json_encode($arr));
fclose($txt_file);
```

path.txt contains:

```
3 October 2005
quera1:today
quera2:tomorrow
quera3:yesterday
quera4:today
```

and the final INFO.json file is:

```
[{"user":"quera4","time":"2005-10-03"}]
```

it only has the last element.

Comment: You compare `$str[1] == "today"` as `$str = 'name'.$i;` it will try and compare `a` with today/tomorrow, you probably meant to use `$date`.  Also not sure why you set `$date` and then do another `if` - why not do it in one set of statements?

Comment: @NigelRen yes I corrected that and I'm actually reading from a file. I converted the code into this.

Comment: As you have updated the code, I have tried it and get 3 elements in the output.

Comment: @NigelRen I added the actual code. could u pls take a look.

Comment: `fgets()` will include the new line from the input - use `trim(fgets($txt_file))`.  This can show why using the proper code is much easier sometimes than trying to use other code.

Comment: @NigelRen it works! thank u. yes I falsely assumed the problem was array syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a file `fgets()` will include the new line from the input so you have a trailing new line when trying to compare it with the text.  Use `trim()` to remove any extra characters...

```
$str = explode(':', trim(fgets($txt_file)));
```